# Document scroll height in Vue not working

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, dom, height

I'm aiming to retrieve the full scrollable height of my page using:

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```

but all I get back is the height of the viewport and not the full height of the scrollable page.

I'm running this in a method that is called after mounted. It's even in a nexttick function. I need this to randomly place images over the full height of the page. It could be something to do with Vue's reactivity(?) and the DOM not updating quick enough for my method to get the full document height?

What is a different way I can get the scroll height of a document in Vue that will actually work?

```
<script>
export default {
data() {
 return {
   images: [
     require("@/assets/img/icons/1.png"),
     require("@/assets/img/icons/2.png"),
   ],
   addedImage: [],
   imgTop: 150,
   imgLeft: 900,
   imgHeight: 64,
   imgWidth: 64,
   selectedImage: "",
   nextId: 100,
 };
},
mounted() {
 this.randomImage();
 this.$nextTick(() => {
   for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
     this.randomImage();
     this.addImage();
     this.randomPosition();
   }
 });
},

methods: {
 randomImage() {
   const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length);
   this.selectedImage = this.images[idx];
 },
 randomPosition() {
   const randomPos = (twoSizes) => Math.round(Math.random() * twoSizes);
   this.imgTop = randomPos(document.body.scrollHeight - this.imgHeight);
   this.imgLeft = randomPos(window.innerWidth - this.imgWidth);
 },
 addImage() {
   this.addedImage.push({
     style: {
       top: `${this.imgTop}px`,
       left: `${this.imgLeft}px`,
       height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
       width: `${this.imgWidth}px`,
     },
     src: this.selectedImage,
     id: this.nextId++,
   });

 },

},
};
</script>
```

Comment: have you set height: 100% on the body?

Comment: Had me wondering for a second! But yeah..body height is set to 100%

Comment: that means the maximum height for the body is the viewport height

Comment: I've just removed height: 100% for body and still the same issue

Comment: A workaround that is doing the trick so far: Rather than putting this component in App.vue and it being a sibling of the component that contains the page content, I've nested it inside the content component. With it being a child of the content component this seems to work and the full body height is calculated correctly